# What are some important examples of differential objects that aren't naturally graded?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

[By a "differential object" I mean an object $A$ in some abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ together with a morphism $d : A \to A$ such that $d \circ d = 0$.  By a "differential module" I mean a differential object in the category $\mathcal{A} = R\text{-mod}$ for some (commutative, unital) ring $R$ -- in particular I do *not* mean a module over a ring equipped with a derivation, though the same term is sometimes used for that.]

The idea of approaching homological algebra by considering differential objects as fundamental and graded things like chain complexes as special cases is attractive to me, because I'm not a big fan of indices.  However, the main examples of differential objects that I'm familiar with are just the objects $A := \bigoplus_i C_i$, where

$\cdots \to C_{i+1} \xrightarrow{d_{i+1}} C_i \xrightarrow{d_i} C_{i-1} \to \cdots$

is a chain complex.

What are some examples of important differential modules that don't come with a natural grading?  (By "important," I mean things that come up in actual problems rather than things constructed specifically to give an example of this phenomenon.)

(One answer I know of is "an abstract spectral sequence," but in practice my understanding is that those are usually bigraded.  I don't know much about those, though, so if someone just wants to list some spectral sequences whose pages aren't bigraded $R$-modules then that would be a helpful answer.)

Comment: What's wrong with indices? The category of chain complexes of objects in an abelian category $A$ concentrated in non-negative degree is equivalent to the category of simplicial objects in $A$ (the Dold-Kan correspondence). That makes them quite natural.

Comment: One reason people consider differential objects is that the same differential object typically has more than one natural filtration (example: the total complex of a double complex). Each filtration naturally gives rise to a spectral sequence and under some conditions on the filtration, this spectral sequence converges to the homology of the differential object.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: my problems with indices are purely psychological.

Comment: (I also don't really know what a simplicial object is; maybe that would be a more convincing explanation if I had a feel for what that meant.)

Comment: I agree with Qiaochu's comment, however I think that it just hides the indices away in the category $\Delta$ which is defined combinatorially.