# How far is a differential module from a chain complex?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

**Motivation**: I assume here, for simplicity, that a differential module is an abelian group $A$ with an endomorphism $d\in End(A)$ which satisfies the relation $d^2=0$. That is, we have all the ingredients to take a homology and so to do homological algebra, except that we forget (or more precisely don't have) the indices. And, actually I am only interested in free chain complexes or free differential modules for some reason that I hinted below.

I'm aware of [the usefulness of having indices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402683/what-are-some-important-examples-of-differential-objects-that-arent-naturally-g), of course, as a graduate student well-educated in algebraic topology. But when we learn homological algebra, the role of indices is not very crucial; at least in a sense that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a canonical choice, and indeed we can safely replace the index set to be, say, $\mathbb{Z}/2$ without modifying the proofs in any essentially new way. (I know, this is quite a lenient description of the business; you can just read up the proofs and see nothing changes at all.)

And, for some mathematicians, the natural choice of index is already given from the situation at hand. Like in singular chain complexes, CW version of it, or whatever chain complexes that is given to you. (You are mostly not expected to call the object at hand a chain complex if there is no index, I guess...)

But I can say for sure that there is at least one group of mathematicians that says the notion of chain complexes without indices: Floer theorist.

The Floer chain complexes that are considered in literature are usually "not given at first", or "in some cases, given after a bunch of geometric considerations that is not trivial and not canonical". And Floer theorist usually just says the object a chain complex. (which should have been called a free differential module.) And it seems most of the homological algebras work as well in this setting, say we can define filtered differential module and do some spectral sequence etc.

So, as a skeptic who is too lazy to check all the details by his own hand, I want to ask: what can be a (nontrivial) difference in considering differential modules instead of chain complexes? Especially about the possible difference between free differential modules and chain complexes of free modules, say. A candidate for such difference might be: a category of differential modules don't have nice properties like having colimits or limits (it seems not very convincing though), ...

Comment: Of course the category of differential modules is complete and cocomplete, since it is algebraic.

Comment: From a practical point of view, duality can work better for a chain complex: if the chain complex is finite rank in each dimension but not finite rank as a whole, then the graded dual is well-behaved but the ungraded dual (i.e., treating it as a single differential module and trying to dualize) will not be as pleasant.

Comment: @HeinrichD I'm not good at category theory, especially don't understand exactly what you mean by being algebraic, but I do believe that the argument goes exactly the same as in case of usual chain complexes. A silly question I made, now that I think of...

Comment: One question which occurs to me is: what do you want a free differential module to be? There are two adjectives 'free' and 'differential' and one interpretation is  that you want a free module plus differential.  The other would be some sort of free object in the category of differential modules.  That would be interesting as you would need some notion of differential set or similar and that is not at all obvious, yet I think that this harder notion should be checked up on. `Free' on what?

Comment: Continuing: a differential free module (i.e. the first sense) would be very like a chain complex of free modules, but the second sense might require a basis which was closed under application of d.

Comment: @TimPorter I think that the first notion is what commonly apears in literature, which simplifies the homological algebra a lot. I'm not an algebraist, so I haven't thought about the second notion seriously... But still I totally agree on your opinion that there is little difference between the first notion and the usual notion of chain complexes. I just wondered if the usual methods in homological algebra, like Ext functors, derived categories, etc work equally well in this new setup.

Comment: Take a chain complex $(C_n,d)$ and form $A=\bigoplus C_n$ the direct sum of all the groups of chains. The differential of the chain complex gives a differential $d:A\to A$, so gives a differential module. On the other hand starting with a differential module $A$ you can form a chain complex by taking $A$ in all dimensions and the d giving the (chain complex) differential. What is missing therefore is some notion of grade or dimension when comparing the two notions. BTW Mac Lane in his book Homology starts with differential groups before introducing the gradied version.

Comment: The  linked question discussed this aspect. My point was that differential free module might be better than free differential module as a name for these beasties.